# Get div direction when using dir="auto" in HTML5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with the dir attribute set to auto.

I want to get the rendered direction using javascript

when I've tried div.dir I get the 'auto' value. is there a way to determine whether the div was rendered as rtl or ltr?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var renderedDirection = window.getComputedStyle(theDiv, null).direction;`